# golang httptest with POST returning runtime error/not posting

Tags: go, httprequest

I'm writing a test for a simple login route with just 2 required params but when I try to post it, it comes back with a runtime error when the header is added. When the header `application/json` is removed the error goes away but it is unable to read the payload.

`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "strings"
    "testing"

    "github.com/gigilaw/ultihats/routes"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

func TestRegisterEmailRoute(t *testing.T) {
    router := routes.ApiRoutes()

    payload := strings.NewReader(`{
        "email":"abc@gmail.com",
        "password": "abc12345"
        }`,
    )

    w := httptest.NewRecorder()
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", "/login", payload)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    router.ServeHTTP(w, req)
    assert.Equal(t, 200, w.Code)
}
```

`

Error
`

```
2022/11/02 18:32:35 [Recovery] 2022/11/02 - 18:32:35 panic recovered:
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json


runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:260 (0x104f8d5)
        panicmem: panic(memoryError)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:835 (0x104f8a5)
        sigpanic: panicmem()
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.24.0/gorm.go:372 (0x1698f18)
        (*DB).getInstance: if db.clone > 0 {
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/pkg/mod/gorm.io/gorm@v1.24.0/chainable_api.go:279 (0x1691995)
        (*DB).Preload: tx = db.getInstance()
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/src/github.com/gigilaw/ultihats/api/controllers/authController.go:64 (0x16d894e)
        UserLogin: initializers.DB.Preload("DiscSkills").First(&user, "email = ?", login.Email)
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/context.go:173 (0x1538181)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/recovery.go:101 (0x153816c)
        CustomRecoveryWithWriter.func1: c.Next()
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/context.go:173 (0x1537286)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/logger.go:240 (0x1537269)
        LoggerWithConfig.func1: c.Next()
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/context.go:173 (0x1536350)
        (*Context).Next: c.handlers[c.index](c)
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/gin.go:616 (0x1535fb8)
        (*Engine).handleHTTPRequest: c.Next()
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/pkg/mod/github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.8.1/gin.go:572 (0x1535afc)
        (*Engine).ServeHTTP: engine.handleHTTPRequest(c)
/Users/gigilaw/Desktop/go/src/github.com/gigilaw/ultihats/api/tests/userTest_test.go:31 (0x171d946)
        TestRegisterEmailRoute: router.ServeHTTP(w, req)
/usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1446 (0x111d70a)
        tRunner: fn(t)
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1594 (0x106db80)
        goexit: BYTE    $0x90   // NOP
```

`

Comment: File `/github.com/gigilaw/ultihats/api/controllers/authController.go` line `64` is where the origin of the panic is. And the reason for the panic is that `initializers.DB` is `nil`. In other words, you've initialized the db incorrectly, or not at all.